# Not able to use key-down event correctly in angularjs Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am   writing   Directive  for validation. I  have   input  field  employee number.when i enter first  digit  i am  not   able  to get  value  what  i  entered.when i  enter  2nd digit
i  am able to  get  first  digit..

Html  code

```
  <input   type="text"  maxlength="7"  ng-model="empno" emp-validator   >
```

Directive code

```
   app.directive('empValidator',function(){
         return  {
           restrict: 'A',
           link : function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl)
             {
               var keyCode =      [8,9,37,39,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,110];
           elem.bind("keydown", function(event) {
            if($.inArray(event.which,keyCode) == -1) {
              scope.$apply(function(){
                 event.preventDefault();

                      }); 
                   }
               console.log("Emp No"+scope.empno);
                }
              }
```

For   first  time   i  get Emp No undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In order to capture the full string in your directive you will need to handle a different event, I would suggest working off of keypress ([jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)) so that you get the full value of the input box in your directive.

Comment: I think you did not read  or  understand  my question.. when i  enter  something  for  first time  i  get  'undefined'  error in  mozilla console. when i enter  something  2nd  time   i get  value of what i enter first time..

Comment: ah, sorry, that's because you have no value, the model doesn't update until keypressed, or keyup. So the event you're handling is firing before the key that you've pressed has been applied. If the value is aaa, and you press the b key, the value will still be aaa at the time of this event.

Comment: so which event should i use?

Comment: keypress and you can find the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/keypress/ (I updated my answer to reflect this)